Linear programming - Why the optimal solutions are in my case the minimum observed values in the dataset?
import pandas as pd
from pulp import LpProblem, LpVariable, lpSum, LpMinimize, LpStatus

# Sample hospital data

data1 = {
'Hospital_ID': range(1, 11),
'Cost_Per_Nurse_Hour': [50, 55, 60, 45, 52, 58, 53, 49, 56, 54],
'Cost_Per_Doctor_Hour': [5000, 4500, 4000, 5500, 4800, 5100, 4700, 4900, 5200, 4600],
'Doctor_Hours': [100, 110, 95, 105, 108, 115, 98, 102, 107, 103],
'Nurse_Hours': [200, 190, 180, 210, 195, 205, 198, 215, 190, 200],
'Total_Patients': [150, 160, 145, 155, 148, 162, 149, 153, 158, 146],
'Hospital_Revenue': [80000, 75000, 82000, 78000, 79000, 81000, 79000, 80500, 79500, 81500],
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data1)
# Create the optimization problem
prob = LpProblem("Maximize_Margin_Labor", LpMinimize)

# Define decision variables 
nurse_hours_ = LpVariable("Nurse_Hours",lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
doctor_hours_ = LpVariable("Doctor_Hours",lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

# Objective function (minimize labor cost/ revenue ratio)
total_labor_cost = nurse_hours_ * lpSum(data.loc[i,"Cost_Per_Nurse_Hour"] for i in  
data.index) + doctor_hours_ * lpSum(data.loc[i,"Cost_Per_Doctor_Hour"] for i in data.index)
margin_labor = total_labor_cost / lpSum(data["Hospital_Revenue"])*100
prob += margin_labor
prob +=nurse_hours_>=190# minimum nurse hours observed
prob +=nurse_hours_<=215# maximum nurse hours observed
prob+=doctor_hours_>=95# minimum doctor hours observed
prob+=doctor_hours_<=115# maximum doctor hours observed
prob +=nurse_hours_-2.1*doctor_hours_<=0 #2.1 maximum observed Nurse Hours/Doctor Hours
prob +=nurse_hours_-1.73*doctor_hours_>=0 #1.73 minimum observed Nurse Hours/Doctor Hours
# Solve the problem
status = prob.solve()

# Print the results
print("Solver status:", LpStatus[status])


optimal_nurse_hours = int(nurse_hours_.value())
optimal_doctor_hours = int(doctor_hours_.value())

# Calculate labor cost and labor cost/revenue ratio for the optimal solutions
total_labor_cost = optimal_nurse_hours * lpSum(data["Cost_Per_Nurse_Hour"]) +          
optimal_doctor_hours * lpSum(data["Cost_Per_Doctor_Hour"])

print("Optimal Nurse Hours:", optimal_nurse_hours)#190 minimum nurse hours observed
print("Optimal Doctor Hours:", optimal_doctor_hours)#95 minimum doctor hours observed
print("Margin Labor Percentage:", margin_labor_percentage, "%")

This code gives the optimal solutions being the minimum observed values. How can I avoid this? I would expect at least one solution to be different than the minimum observed value. What other constraints can be added? Thank you.

Have you gone through this manually?  You seem to be optimizing for minimum labor cost, so it's not at all surprising that the optimum would be at the minimums, is it?

I ran this by hand.  Your result is exactly what I would expect.  What you are asking is simply "how many hours should people work to minimize the labor cost"?  Naturally, the answer is "as few as possible".  To make this a real problem, you need to balance the labor cost against the revenue value provided by that labor, but you're not doing that.  Your revenue is constant.

Thank you for the reply Tim. Yes, I plotted the feasible region. So I understand then that I do not need to use this optimization method since I just can find the minimum values by looking at the dataset. I was thinking that adding more constraints could change the shape of the feasible region and it could potentially eliminate the lower left vertex of the feasible region. What do you think?

So I need to write the revenue as a function of the decision variables (Sum of (Hospital Revenue per Nurse Hour * X+ Hospital Revenue per Doctor Hour * Y), where X and Y are the decision variables)?

I don't think you are asking the question you really want to ask.  I assume you are trying to investigate hospital productivity in some way, but to do that, you have to compute things like "revenue per labor dollar" or "revenue per patient".  Look at this example:
import pandas as pd

# Sample hospital data

data1 = {
'Hospital_ID': range(1, 11),
'Cost_Per_Nurse_Hour': [50, 55, 60, 45, 52, 58, 53, 49, 56, 54],
'Cost_Per_Doctor_Hour': [5000, 4500, 4000, 5500, 4800, 5100, 4700, 4900, 5200, 4600],
'Doctor_Hours': [100, 110, 95, 105, 108, 115, 98, 102, 107, 103],
'Nurse_Hours': [200, 190, 180, 210, 195, 205, 198, 215, 190, 200],
'Total_Patients': [150, 160, 145, 155, 148, 162, 149, 153, 158, 146],
'Hospital_Revenue': [80000, 75000, 82000, 78000, 79000, 81000, 79000, 80500, 79500, 81500],
}

for i in range(10):
    labor_cost = \
        data1['Cost_Per_Nurse_Hour'][i] * data1['Nurse_Hours'][i] + \
        data1['Cost_Per_Doctor_Hour'][i] * data1['Doctor_Hours'][i]
    revenue_per_labor = data1['Hospital_Revenue'][i] / labor_cost
    revenue_per_patient = data1['Hospital_Revenue'][i] / data1['Total_Patients'][i]
    print(i+1,revenue_per_labor,revenue_per_patient)

Output:
1 0.1568627450980392 533.3333333333334
2 0.14838262934019192 468.75
3 0.2098259979529171 565.5172413793103
4 0.132890365448505 503.2258064516129
5 0.1494683467665645 533.7837837837837
6 0.1353632246528184 500.0
7 0.16769477004589317 530.2013422818792
8 0.15773952403813182 526.1437908496732
9 0.1402017494356659 503.1645569620253
10 0.16817994222038796 558.2191780821918

What this tells is is that hospital 3 is getting the best revenue per labor hour (by far), and is also getting the best revenue per patient ratio.  A real productivity measure would probably combine these in some way.
The tools can only help you if you know what you want to learn.

You are right Tim :) And your example is really helpful. What I am trying to find is one optimal ratio of Nurse Hours/ Doctor Hours that minimizes the labor cost/revenue. What would you suggest in this case? Thanks.

Well, since you only have 10 data points, you could actually plot nurse_hours/doctor_hours against total_labor/revenue.  However, even that doesn't give you the whole picture, because that ignores the number of patients.

Yes, it looks like I would need somehow to add the number of patients. Not sure how.
